# Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2

Tags: node.js, oracle11g

Even though I have searched for the solution of this error and i found some answers but none of them helped me fix this error, `Error: NJS-012: encountered invalid bind data type in parameter 2`.Maybe, one error can occur in a different scenarios.

### Stored procedure definition

```
create or replace PROCEDURE SP_MEAL_GETMEALTYPES
(
 p_DataSource   OUT   Sys_RefCursor
)
AS
BEGIN
      OPEN p_DataSource FOR 
     select mealtypeid,description from mealtypes;
END;
```

### File name: menusStoredProc.js

```
"use strict";

var dbParams = require('../../oracle/dbParams');
function storedProcs() {

    this.SP_USER_GETMENUS = {
        name: 'sp_meal_getmealtypes',
        params: {
        dataSource: {val: null, type: dbParams.CURSOR, dir: dbParams.BIND_OUT}
        },
        resultSetColumns: ['mealTypeId','description']

    }
}

module.exports = storedProcs;
```

### File name: menus.js

```
var express = require('express');
var MenusStoreProc = require('../storedProcedures/menusStoredProc');
var oraDbAssist = require('../../oracle/oracleDbAssist');
var router = express.Router();

router.get('/getmenus', (req, res, next) => {
    var sp = new MenusStoreProc().SP_USER_GETMENUS;
    oraDbAssist.getConnection(function (err, conn) {
        if (err)
            return console.log('Connecting to db failed - ' + err);

        oraDbAssist.executeSqlWithConn(sp, false, conn, function (err, menus) {
            if (err)
                return console.log('Executing ' + sp.name + ' failed - ' + err);

            res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(menus));
        });

    });

});
module.exports = router;
```

### Function definition added - executeSqlWithConn

```
function executeSqlWithConn(sp, autoCommit, connection, next) {
    var sql = createProcedureSqlString(sp.name, sp.params);
    var params = buildParams(sp.params);
    connection.execute(sql, params, {autoCommit: autoCommit}, function(err, result) {
        if (err) {
            next(err, null);
            return;
        }

        var allRows = [];
        var numRows = 50;  // number of rows to return from each call to getRows()

        for(var attributeName in result.outBinds) {
            if(result.outBinds[attributeName] && result.outBinds[attributeName].metaData) { // db response is a result set

                function fetchRowsFromResultSet(pResultSet, pNumRows) {
                    pResultSet.getRows(pNumRows, function(readErr, rows) {
                        if(err) {
                            pResultSet.close(function (err) { // always close the result set
                                next(readErr);                                
                            });
                            return;
                        }

                        allRows.push(rows);
                        if (rows.length === pNumRows) {
                            fetchRowsFromResultSet(result.outBinds[attributeName], numRows);
                            return;
                        }

                        var allRowsResult = Array.prototype.concat.apply([], allRows);

                        generateJsonFromDbResultSet(pResultSet.metaData, allRowsResult, sp, function(resultSet) {
                            pResultSet.close(function (err) { // always close the result set
                                next(null, resultSet);
                            });
                        });
                    });
                }

                fetchRowsFromResultSet(result.outBinds[attributeName], numRows);
                return;
            }
        }
        next(null, result.outBinds);
    });
}
```

### Function definition added - buildParams

```
function buildParams(params) {

    for(var attributeName in params) {
        params[attributeName].val = typeof params[attributeName].val === 'undefined' ? null : params[attributeName].val;

        if(params[attributeName].type.is(dbParams.DATE))
            params[attributeName].val = params[attributeName].val ? new Date(params[attributeName].val) : null;

        params[attributeName].type = params[attributeName].type.value;
        params[attributeName].dir = params[attributeName].dir.value;

    }

    return params;
}
```

Any help, dear members ?

Comment: Add `oraDbAssist.executeSqlWithConn` to the code that you're displaying. Also, you  may be interested in this series on creating a REST API with Node.js and Oracle Database: https://jsao.io/2018/03/creating-a-rest-api-with-node-js-and-oracle-database/

Comment: @DanMcGhan, just updated the post by adding the definition of the function you asked for. Please check it again.

Comment: Add the definition of `buildParams`.

Comment: @DanMcGhan Definition of `buildParams` function is added. Check it again please.

Comment: Unfortunately, running your code seems pretty difficult. Where is `.type.is` coming from? Is this part of a test suite? Let's try another approach. In the `executeSqlWithConn` function, between where you call `buildParams` and `connection.execute`, please add this line and show me the result: `console.log(params)`

Comment: @DanMcGhan `params = {"dataSource":{"val":null,"type":2004,"dir":3003}}`

Comment: I don't think that's the exact `console.log` output, but based on what you've shown (the keys are all wrapped in double quotes), I think you are doing a `JSON.stringify` on the object before passing it to `connection.execute`. `connection.execute` is expecting a JavaScript object, not a JSON string.

Comment: You are right, i was doing that but even putting it here shows the error !
`oraDbAssist.executeSqlWithConn(sp, false, conn, function (err, menus) {
            if (err){
                console.log('params:\t'+ JSON.stringify(sp.params));
                return console.log('Executing ' + sp.name + ' failed - ' + err);
            }
            res.status(200).json(JSON.stringify(menus));
        });`

Comment: I don't know what you're talking about. Please try to understand what I'm saying. The second parameter you are passing to `connection.execute` is a string because you stringified it. Don't do that.

Comment: @DanMcGhan when `"oracledb": "^3.1.2"` and `node-v8.11.3-x64.msi`  used , the error is gone and the expected result is returned from db.

Comment: If you believe you've found a bug, you will need to provide a reproducible test case that you can hand over to us with instructions on how to reproduce the error.

Comment: @DanMcGhan, thanks. It was not actually a bug that i found but it was my poor understanding of how Oracle and Nodejs work together.
I had the latest versions of `Nodejs`  and `Oracledb` module installed with `type constants` of an old version of `Oracledb` package. This link below helped me fix the issue. I will post it as an answer soon.
http://oracle.github.io/node-oracledb/doc/api.html#oracledbconstantsnodbtype

Comment: I think I get it now, you cashed some constants in your own wrapper package and got burned when they changed in the actual library. Well, at least you were able to figure it out! :)

Comment: @DanMcGhan, Exactly, you got it.